# How to fire a CSS transition before unloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, load, css-transitions

I want some simple page transition for a website when the user enters the page and leaves it.

For now I decided to go with a simple CSS transition. I added an element to my page, `.amb-preloader` which is by default a grey rectangle covering the complete screen. When the page is loaded, I add a class to the element which makes the rectangle disappear:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.amb-preloader').addClass('amb-loaded');
});
```

Now I want sth similar, but opposite, for when the user clicks a link. The class `.amb-loaded` should be removed from the `.amb-preloader` and then the grey rectangle appears (takes 600ms). After those 600ms, when the grey rectangle is in front of everyting, the browser should go to the next page as usual.

I did this like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var element = $(this);
    
    $(this).preventDefault();
    
    $('.amb-preloader').removeClass('amb-loaded');
    $(this).trigger('click');
    
});
```

This behaviour works very nice in all browsers, except Safari. On all my Apple devices Safari doesn't work.

I checked this with the console in Safari and it gives me the error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. I searched for this on the internet and it says that a function calls to itself and therefore keeps looping.

I don't know why it doesn't work in Safari and it does in other browsers. Do you have any idea what I should do to fix it on Safari? Or are there better alternatives to this animation?

Perhaps the full error message can be of some help:

```
[Error] RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
    n (jquery.js:2:420)
    pushStack (jquery.js:2:764)
    find (jquery.js:2:24069)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8937)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:2:24601)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:3143)
    n (jquery.js:2:420)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:17)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:11494)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery-migrate.min.js:2:8280)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:18873)
    each (jquery.js:2:2908)
    each (jquery.js:2:851)
    trigger (jquery.js:3:18846)
    (anonieme functie) (pageload.js:18)
    dispatch (jquery.js:3:12375)
    (anonieme functie) (jquery.js:3:9094)
```

(anonieme functie = anonymous function, literal translation from Dutch)

Many thanks!

**FINAL SOLUTION**

Thanks to the answer of StefanN, which I modified a little bit, the final solution code is as follows:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  var element = $(this);

  event.preventDefault();
    
  if ($('.amb-preloader').hasClass('amb-loaded')) {
    $('.amb-preloader').removeClass('amb-loaded');    
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = url;
    }, 300);
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  var element = $(this);

  $(this).preventDefault
  if ($('.amb-preloader').hasClass('amb-loaded')) {
    $('.amb-preloader').removeClass('amb-loaded');
    $(this).trigger('click');
  } else {
    return;
  }
});
```

Your code renders in an infinite loop. This will result in another click:
$(this).trigger('click');

The solution is that you add a check if the className is still assigned to the element. If so: proceed and trigger another click. If not: return;